# Celery back-end failure?

Tags: python, memory, erlang, rabbitmq, celery

I messed something up somewhere.

I'm using celery to run a task that runs other tasks. I'm using RabbitMQ as my back-end.

When I start-up my computer, I immediately have `erl.exe` taking up 50% of my CPU resources and several gigs of RAM. If I let it go, the RAM usage will continue to climb pretty steadily. (the drop is when I ended the process)

[image: taskmgr]

If I end the process, celery beat/workers error out out with

```
[2014-04-17 12:35:07,869: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

If I don't end the process, the workers and the beat just spit out the config info and then hang.

If I try to use `discard_all()` it also hangs while the RAM usage steadily climbs.

Is there a way I can reset erlang without going through celery? I don't care about anything in the queue, it's all dev stuff.

**EDIT:**

Here is the end of my rabbitmq log file.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:20:41 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.2.4 on Erlang R16B03-1
Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:20:41 ===
node           : rabbit@myComputer
home dir       : C:\Windows
config file(s) : (none)
cookie hash    : +z4Hn5WvfV2DO2xSryp0/Q==
log            : C:/Users/myUser/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@myComputer.log
sasl log       : C:/Users/myUser/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/rabbit@myComputer-sasl.log
database dir   : c:/Users/myUser/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/rabbit@myComputer-mnesia

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:20:44 ===
Limiting to approx 8092 file handles (7280 sockets)

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:20:45 ===
Memory limit set to 9829MB of 24573MB total.

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:20:45 ===
Disk free limit set to 50MB

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:24:57 ===
msg_store_transient: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:24:57 ===
msg_store_persistent: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=WARNING REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:24:57 ===
msg_store_persistent: rebuilding indices from scratch

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:26:48 ===
started TCP Listener on [::]:5672

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:26:49 ===
started TCP Listener on 0.0.0.0:5672

=WARNING REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:35:04 ===
file descriptor limit alarm set.

********************************************************************
*** New connections will not be accepted until this alarm clears ***
********************************************************************

=WARNING REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:35:05 ===
file descriptor limit alarm cleared

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:35:05 ===
Server startup complete; 0 plugins started.

=WARNING REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:35:06 ===
file descriptor limit alarm set.

********************************************************************
*** New connections will not be accepted until this alarm clears ***
********************************************************************

=WARNING REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:35:07 ===
file descriptor limit alarm cleared

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:37:40 ===
vm_memory_high_watermark set. Memory used:10558805712 allowed:10306889318

=WARNING REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:37:40 ===
memory resource limit alarm set on node 'rabbit@myComputer'.

**********************************************************
*** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
**********************************************************

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:37:41 ===
vm_memory_high_watermark clear. Memory used:10087183696 allowed:10306889318

=WARNING REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:37:41 ===
memory resource limit alarm cleared on node 'rabbit@myComputer'

=INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:38:04 ===
vm_memory_high_watermark set. Memory used:10323681952 allowed:10306889318

=WARNING REPORT==== 17-Apr-2014::13:38:04 ===
memory resource limit alarm set on node 'rabbit@myComputer'.

**********************************************************
*** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
**********************************************************
```

Comment: Can you query RabbitMQ while this is happening to see if a queue is growing out of control or something? I'm not sure what's available for this on Windows, but on Linux I'd use `rabbitmqctl list_queues`.

Comment: @dano That also seems to hang. I don't know how long it's supposed to take, but it's been a couple minutes and it hasn't displayed anything yet. EDIT: Also it seemed to have made the RAM usage jump up. by a few GB.

Comment: Seems like RabbitMQ is having some issues, then. The list_queues command should finish instantly. I would see if you can find the logs for RabbitMQ and look for a smoking gun of some kind (sorry, I'm only familiar with running it on Linux, so I can't help much here).

Comment: @dano Alright, RAM usage went up until I had to kill the process. When I did, `rabbitmqctl list_queues` failed. I will the last bit of my log file as an edit. Unfortunately I don't really know what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up:

1. Uninstalling RabbitMQ and Erlang.
2. Removed `C:\Users\username\AppData\RabbitMQ`
3. Restarted because at least one piece of Erlang (epmd.exe) was still running.
4. Reinstalled Erlang and RabbitMQ.

Hello, IT. Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I was having the same problem, and I reinstalled RabbitMQ and Erlang multiple times, and it worked only when I did it in the specific order you wrote (deleting folder and restarting before reinstalling). Thanks